# Getting error ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Angular application on refreshing page

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on Angular 2 application that is consuming Web API 2, that is develop in .NET Core 2.0. my implementation worked so far with no problem until now. for first instance click event web api consume successfully and any refresh of page or starting same cycle only for this specific code throw error

```
ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

### Code which cause error

```
@Component({
selector: 'current-response-references',
templateUrl: './current-responses.template.html',
styleUrls: ['./current-responses.style.scss'],
providers:[ 
  ]
})

export class CurrentResponsesReferencesComponent implements OnInit {

private view: BehaviorSubject<ConsulationResponsesIdListDataModel>;
private consultationResponses: ConsulationResponsesIdListDataModel;
private responseCurrentState: ResponseCurrentStateDataModel;

constructor(private dataService: ConsultationResponsesListDataService,
    private router: Router,
    private session: SessionStorageService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.view = new BehaviorSubject<ConsulationResponsesIdListDataModel>(null);
    this.consultationResponses = new ConsulationResponsesIdListDataModel();

    this.loadData();
}

public loadData():void{

    var consultationId = this.session.getItem('consultationId');
    // following code believe causing error where similar code some else works fine
     this.dataService.getConsultationResponsesList(consultationId)
     .subscribe(data =>{
       debugger;
          this.view.next(data);
          console.log("responses list ....", data);

     });     
  }
```

### above code using in following component's template

```
   this code is navigated from another component as 
   this.router.navigate(['modules/newResponseQuestions']);
```

..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'new-response-questions',
  templateUrl: './new-response-question.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-response-question.style.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   providers: [
  ]
})
export class NewResponseComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private session: SessionStorageService){}

ngOnInit(): void {

}
```

### above code template (new-response-question.template.html)

is template reference from component where I am getting error, refer to first block of code above

```
<div class="card-block">   
        <current-response-references></current-response-references>
        <questionsDetailList></questionsDetailList>       
</div>
```

Comment: Is the protocol error for one of the ajax requests, or for angular page itself? Does `getConsultationResponsesList` return a lot of data?

Comment: no, in current instance is only two record

Comment: I test on chrome and other browser, same issue

Comment: @toxic did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I have the same issue in my application. If you have a solution to this please share.